# DNS lookup fails when with all the Mac workstations

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx, mac-osx-server

I am having this insane problem. We are Mac heavy users. Around 10 workstations, one Xserve server, two Windows workstation and one Linux (me). Last year I added an A record to our domain's DNS. However we had to change that a few months ago to a new IP. But all the Mac workstations fail to resolve the proper DNS and they still resolve to the old IP, even after 2 months.

On both the Windows workstation and my Linux box a simple nslookup resolves to proper IP. However, on ALL the Mac workstation, dig and nslookup report the old IP address.

From my linux workstation:

> jp@lo:~$ nslookup - 208.67.222.222
>
> client.xyz.com
>
> Server:  208.67.222.222
>
> Address: 208.67.222.222#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
>
> Name: client.xyz.com
>
> Address: 68.71.40.xx

But when I am trying the exact same command from any Mac workstation, I get the old IP:

> $ nslookup - 208.67.222.222
>
> client.xyz.com
>
> Server:  208.67.222.222
>
> Address: 208.67.222.222#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
>
> Name: client.xyz.com
>
> Address: 98.143.155.xx

The strange thing is that this only happens in our internal network. No problem from home nor from another server. I did try to flush the DNS, don't worry. It did not help.

I am starting to wonder if my router (OpenWRT) or Mac OS X Server is not in some way spoofing the DNS request and thus acting as a cache.

Any suggestions/comments would be grateful.
Thank you,
JP

Comment: Some OpenWRT boxes I have seen run dnsmasq which does proxy, but if you specify the DNS server explicitly I've never seen this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

- What version(s) of Mac OS X?
- What do their DNS settings in "System Preferences > Network > $INTERFACE > Advanced > DNS" show? It'll be interesting to know what DNS server address(es) they show, and if it's manually configured (black) or if they're getting it from DHCP (grey)
- If they're using DHCP, what does `ipconfig getpacket en0` show? (Replace en0 with the designator of the interface they're connecting with.) This will show which DNS servers your DHCP server is telling that Mac to use.
- What does `cat /etc/resolv.conf` say?
- What does `cat /etc/hosts` say?
- Am I correct to assume you rebooted the Macs and the problem persisted?